How to Improve JSON Saving Efficiency in Parallel Processing with Python?
I'm currently working on a Python script that involves parallel processing using multiprocessing, where I make API calls and save results to JSON files. However, the current implementation saves a separate JSON file for each process, which I find inefficient. I'd like to optimize this process to save all results to a shared JSON file. Here's a simplified version of my code:
def call_api(example):
  # send request
  response = requests.post(MIXSTRAL_URL, json=example['input'])
  results = {}
  # check status
  if check_status(response.status_code):
     query_pred = extraction_pipe(response.text)

     results[example['id']] = {'question': example['question'], 'query_gold': example['query_gold'], 'query_pred': {str(i): query for i, query in enumerate(query_pred)}}

     save_json(example['save_path'], results)


def mixtral_prompting_similarity_parallel(test_ds, train_ds, save_path, prompt, similarities, train_data_rel=None, test_data_rel=None):
  type_example = 'ent_rel_unique' if train_data_rel and test_data_rel else ''
  count = 0
  all_input = {"id": [], "input": [], "question": [], "query_gold": [], "save_path": []}

  # Create input for each question
  for id, question_dict in test_ds.items():
    # create input configuration
    input_config = config.copy()
    prompt_examples = f""
    for sim_id in similarities[id]:
        q_dict = train_data_rel[sim_id] if type_example else train_ds[sim_id]
        prompt_examples += create_example(q_dict, type_example)

    type = type_example if type_example else ''
    q_dict = test_data_rel[id] if type_example else question_dict

    input = create_mixstral_input(q_dict, type)

    input_config['text'] = prompt + prompt_examples + input

    all_input["id"].append(id)
    all_input["input"].append(input_config)
    all_input["question"].append(question_dict['question'])
    all_input["query_gold"].append(question_dict['query'])

    save_path_file = os.path.join(save_path, f'predictions_{id}.json')
    all_input["save_path"].append(save_path_file)

  df = Dataset.from_dict(all_input)
  with multiprocessing.Pool(16) as pool:
       pool.map(call_api, df)

I'd like to modify the call_api function to save all results to a shared JSON file instead of creating a separate file for each process. What would be the best approach to achieve this? Additionally, are there any other optimizations or better formulations that could improve the efficiency of this code? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

JSON has structure which you can't write from different places - because it may create invalid file. You have to get all data and write them in one moment. Besides when you write any file at the same time in different processes then it may create invalid file. You should send all data back to main process and it should write it.

So it is also wrong to save an indepentent file for each process ? @furas

if every process create independent file then it is OK, but if all processes write to the same file then it may create broken file. Every process would have to lock access to file, read all to memory, modify it in memory, and write all back to file, and unlock it. It can't write JSON in append mode. It could use append mode for CVS or multi-JSON where every line is independent JSON

maybe you should use return results in processes and all_results = pool.map(...) to get all results in main process - and later write all results in one file.

Important question: have you profiled your code? If you want to "optimize" things you always need to profile to actually find out where the slowdown is. It is frequently not intuitive where slowdowns actually occur and what is actually faster than you think. I use the spyder IDE, and have gotten used to using its built-in profiling tools (based on cProfile), but every decent IDE likely has some tools for it. Profiling multi-process code is admittedly quite difficult, so I would optimize a single process version first, then work on finding details particular to multiprocessing.

with a quick search, it seems viztracer may be a decent option for profiling multiprocess code. Note: I have no affiliation, and have not used this tool.
